# How to rename an apk package name with aapt / apktool?

Tags: android, aapt, apktool

I'm looking to rename an apk package name with existing tools like aapt or apktool.

Found this question that is related : [Rename package name using aapt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223942/rename-package-name-using-aapt)

I tried to adapt the command `aapt p -f --rename-manifest-package com.mynewpackagename -M AndroidManifest.xml -F myapp.apk -I android.jar -S res`

But it gives an error.

Comment: You can unpack the project using Android Studio and then rename the project that way. It's not a solution but a workaround.

Comment: Provide exact error

Answer (score 2):

You can decompile the apk using apktool: `apktool d apk_path.apk` and change this property in `apk_path/apktool.yml`

```yaml
renameManifestPackage: new.package.name
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be enough. I cannot install modified app on top of existing one with different name

Comment: what error do you get when trying to install the apk?

Comment: was not installing. Anyway i realized i needed to update pkg name references in the smali files, as well as in the smali folder structure and worked without relying on modifying apktool.yml

Comment: usually it's enough to make changes to apktool.yml and maybe AndroidManifest.xml, but yeah, good you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a safe and fast rename package name solution. I recommend using "Android Package Renamer" plugin in Android Studio Or Intellij IDEA.

What you need to do is download it:

- Open Your Project.
- Click -> File -> Rename Package
- Input the Package you want to change.
- Click OK.
- Sync Project with Gradle Files or Invalidate Caches

You can see the [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75362772/13753492) here or go to the github of [this repo](https://github.com/nguyenphuc22/Android-Package-Renamer)